# Sum() up CASE values from joined tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, date-range

I'm creating a hotel booking tool for our desk/reception. My current `SELECT` doesn't compute the "final" `sum()`/`CASE`, meaning that as long as there are more then one overlap (`hb.booking_period && cp.valid_period`) per `booking_ID`, the `CASE` values in the data output only represent shares of the total price. If you sum up those shares, it matches the total price (of the stay). How can I calculate the sums of all these `CASE` results/shares (that fit the related `booking_id`)?

```sql
SELECT
    hb.booking_id,
    hb.guest_name,
    hb.room_category_id,
    hb.booking_period,
    cp.base_price,
    CASE
        WHEN upper(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) = upper(hb.booking_period) THEN
            (upper(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) - lower(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period)) * cp.base_price
        ELSE
            (upper(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) - lower(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) + 1) * cp.base_price
    END

FROM
    hotel_bookings hb
JOIN
    category_prices cp ON hb.room_category_id = cp.room_category_id AND hb.booking_period && cp.valid_period
GROUP BY
    hb.booking_id, hb.guest_name, hb.room_category_id, hb.booking_period, cp.base_price, cp.valid_period;
```

`booking_period` and `valid_period` are daterange datatypes.

The `CASE` ensures that the `intersection * base_price` is calculated correctly, since otherwise for each intersection 1 stay would be lost.

Here are the table definitions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE room_categories 
(
    category_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(25)
);


CREATE TABLE category_prices 
(
    category_price_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    room_category_id INTEGER REFERENCES room_categories(category_id),
    valid_period daterange,
    base_price DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE hotel_bookings 
(
    booking_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    guest_name VARCHAR(255),
    room_category_id INTEGER REFERENCES room_categories(category_id),
    booking_period daterange
);
```

The data:

```sql
INSERT INTO room_categories (category_name) VALUES
    ('single room'),
    ('double room');

INSERT INTO category_prices (room_category_id, valid_period, base_price) VALUES
    (1, '[2023-01-01, 2023-01-31)', 80.00),
    (1, '[2023-02-01, 2023-02-28)', 85.00),
    (1, '[2023-03-01, 2023-03-31)', 88.00),
    (2, '[2023-01-01, 2023-01-31)', 100.00),
    (2, '[2023-02-01, 2023-02-28)', 105.00),
    (2, '[2023-03-01, 2023-03-31)', 108.00);

INSERT INTO hotel_bookings (guest_name, room_category_id, booking_period) VALUES
    ('John Doe', 1, '[2023-01-15, 2023-01-20)'), --correct calced, 1 intersection
    ('Jane Smith', 1, '[2023-01-30, 2023-02-02)'), -- 2 shares (need/want a sumup)
    ('Jane Smith', 1, '[2023-02-25, 2023-03-03)'),
    ('Jordan Miller', 2, '[2023-01-30, 2023-03-02)'); -- 3 shares (need/want a sumup)
```

Comment: It is certainly possible to wrap a `CASE` expression with `SUM()`.  That being said, it is difficult to suggest a fix here because your question lacks sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added tables and data. As you can see there is an extra row with the result for each intersection `hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period`. i want to sum those rows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum(case when a then b else c end)` is perfectly allowed. Looking at your edits with examples, my guess is that you're grouping too deep: the periods and their prices multiply your booking rows, spawning a separate entry for each `hb.booking_period && cp.valid_period` intersection. To collapse them into one row per booking with one valid sum, you can aggregate those, e.g. with [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.15.1.2.1). [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/3HisO3cC)

```
SELECT
    hb.booking_id,
    hb.guest_name,
    hb.room_category_id,
    hb.booking_period,
    jsonb_pretty(jsonb_object_agg(cp.valid_period,cp.base_price)),
    SUM(CASE WHEN  upper(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) = upper(hb.booking_period) 
             THEN (upper(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) - lower(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period)) * cp.base_price
             ELSE (upper(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) - lower(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) + 1) * cp.base_price
        END )
FROM hotel_bookings hb
JOIN category_prices cp 
ON hb.room_category_id = cp.room_category_id 
AND hb.booking_period && cp.valid_period
GROUP BY hb.booking_id, 
  hb.guest_name, 
  hb.room_category_id, 
  hb.booking_period;
```

| booking_id | guest_name | room_category_id | booking_period | jsonb_pretty | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 1 | [2023-01-15,2023-01-20) | {"[2023-01-01,2023-01-31)": 80.00} | 400.00 |
| 2 | Jane Smith | 1 | [2023-01-30,2023-02-02) | {"[2023-01-01,2023-01-31)": 80.00,"[2023-02-01,2023-02-28)": 85.00 } | 245.00 |
| 3 | Jane Smith | 1 | [2023-02-25,2023-03-03) | {"[2023-02-01,2023-02-28)": 85.00, "[2023-03-01,2023-03-31)": 88.00} | 516.00 |
| 4 | Jordan Miller | 2 | [2023-01-30,2023-03-02) | {"[2023-01-01,2023-01-31)": 100.00, "[2023-02-01,2023-02-28)": 105.00, "[2023-03-01,2023-03-31)": 108.00} | 3248.00 |

The reason for that `case` statement is probably that you unintentionally used [upper bound exclusive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) ranges for your category prices. If you make them upper bound inclusive, you can get rid of that whole thing and just multiply the `booking_period*valid_period` intersection length by the `base_price`: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/IVIKkeZ0)

```sql
UPDATE category_prices 
SET valid_period=daterange(lower(valid_period),upper(valid_period),'[]');

SELECT
    hb.booking_id,
    hb.guest_name,
    hb.room_category_id,
    hb.booking_period,
    jsonb_pretty(jsonb_object_agg(cp.valid_period,cp.base_price)),
    SUM((  upper(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period) 
         - lower(hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period)) 
        * cp.base_price )
FROM hotel_bookings hb
JOIN category_prices cp 
ON hb.room_category_id = cp.room_category_id 
AND hb.booking_period && cp.valid_period
GROUP BY hb.booking_id, 
  hb.guest_name, 
  hb.room_category_id, 
  hb.booking_period;
```

See the cheatsheet:

```
select raw,
       dr AS canonicalized,
       lower(dr),
       lower_inc(dr),
       upper(dr),
       upper_inc(dr)
from (values ('(2023-01-01, 2023-01-31)'),
             ('(2023-01-01, 2023-01-31]'),
             ('[2023-01-01, 2023-01-31)'),
             ('[2023-01-01, 2023-01-31]'))AS a(raw),
     lateral (select raw::daterange)AS b(dr);
```

| raw | canonicalized | lower | lower_inc | upper | upper_inc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (2023-01-01, 2023-01-31) | [2023-01-02,2023-01-31) | 2023-01-02 | t | 2023-01-31 | f |
| (2023-01-01, 2023-01-31] | [2023-01-02,2023-02-01) | 2023-01-02 | t | 2023-02-01 | f |
| [2023-01-01, 2023-01-31) | [2023-01-01,2023-01-31) | 2023-01-01 | t | 2023-01-31 | f |
| [2023-01-01, 2023-01-31] | [2023-01-01,2023-02-01) | 2023-01-01 | t | 2023-02-01 | f |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/24Jv1iHR)

Comment: I tried sum() around it, sadly it didnt work (more precisely it works but it doesn't change anything). I also edited the post with data and tables to test.

Comment: It does *work*, in the sense that it's a valid operation (edit: we agree on that). My guess is that the price calculation inside is missing something, or the grouping isn't right.

Comment: how would/should you group it then? I'm new to databases and don't even know where i could start... Maybe something different in the `AND hb.booking_period && cp.valid_period` ?

Comment: @AndreasM. I edited the answer to show an example of alternate grouping, resulting in a single `sum` for each `booking_id`

Comment: you are a beast, thank you so much! Is there a way to shorten the term `hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period` as well? It looks like a big waste of computional power to me (im used to `calced_intersection = hb.booking_period * cp.valid_period` and then use `calced_intersection` instead.

Comment: [The planner](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html) sees the repetition and optimizes that to be computed that just once per row, re-using the result.
You could wrap this in a cte or a subquery to give those expressions an alias to reference by in the outer query, but that'll actually end up making the whole longer, with absolutely no performance gain. In [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/N1bh6wB1) you can see the output of [`explain analyze verbose`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) is exactly the same, and so is the planning/execution time.

Comment: You are right, its either '[]' or '[, +1 day)'. No wonder i had to make a CASE. I was missing the last day of each month.